# SQL - partially order by list of id's

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I have a table which I query, the condition is something like `id >10`, and i want to add a condition based on id's from a list something like `AND id IN(3,4,5,6,7)`.

I want to order the results by the id's from the list first.
can it be done?

Comment: `Order by CASE WHEN id IN(3,4,5,6,7) THEN 0 ELSE 1 END,id`

Comment: which rdbms are you using? in oracle for example you could use a decode in the order by to order these id´s primarly

Comment: Order by CASE WHEN id < 10 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END, id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you're using MySQL: (please tag questions appropriately)

From the [manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_field):

> ***FIELD(str,str1,str2,str3,...)***
>
> Returns the index (position) of str in the str1, str2, str3, ... list. Returns 0 if str is not found.
>
> If all arguments to FIELD() are strings, all arguments are compared as strings. If all arguments are numbers, they are compared as numbers. Otherwise, the arguments are compared as double.
>
> If str is NULL, the return value is 0 because NULL fails equality comparison with any value. FIELD() is the complement of ELT().

```
mysql> SELECT FIELD('ej', 'Hej', 'ej', 'Heja', 'hej', 'foo');
        -> 2
mysql> SELECT FIELD('fo', 'Hej', 'ej', 'Heja', 'hej', 'foo');
        -> 0
```

So you can easily do

```
SELECT
...
ORDER BY FIELD(id, 3,4,5,6,7), id
```

Comment: This is MySQL specific, are you sure OP uses MySQL and not SQL Server?

Comment: Oh, didn't notice. Thanks

Comment: thanks. Tho i use mysql and the solution works, i thought it was some basic sql...